# function to calculate total sale amount

Tags: c#, math

I have a product that sells in a strange way.

The formula to get the current price is:

```
total_products_sold * 0.05
```

I need a function that will return the total sales value, given a total_products_sold value.
This needs to figure out all past pricing, using the above formula.

e.g. if I sold 3 products, the total sales amount is:

```
1 * 0.5 + 2 * 0.5 + 3 * 0.5 = .30
```

I can't remember the formula, if its a factorial issue or a exponential type equation.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me... What language? C#?

Comment: Hm ... you earned 6k rep by asking qs only? By the way you have a typo: 0.05, not 0.5 (or at least I hope that dems did not make the sale tax 50% yet).

Comment: By the way tax * amt1 + tax * amt2 + tax * amt3 = tax * (amt1 + amt2 + amt3).

Comment: Can you use LINQ (because that would be fun)? Basically return tax * sum(ienumerables);

Comment: just letting you know... http://mathoverflow.net/ :)  I ran across that site the other day hehe.

Comment: Nope, they though my question about the meaning of square root of identity matrix was dull ... that site is for pros man. They do not tolerate basic qs.

Comment: I didn't mention tax anywhere? Why are you asking about tax??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formula is

total(N) =
1 * 0.5 + 2 * 0.5 + ... + N * 0.5 =
(1 + 2 + ... + N) * 0.5 = (check [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171225182632/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57919.html))
((N + 1) * N / 2) * 0.5

function could be something like

```
float total (int products) {
    return (products + 1) * products / 2 * 0.5;
}
```

Comment: your brackets might not be correct, but the formula worked thanks!